# Removing a string that startswith a specific char Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
text='I miss Wonderland #feeling sad @omg'
prefix=('#','@')
for line in text:
   if line.startswith(prefix):
      text=text.replace(line,'')
 print(text)
```

The output should be:

```
'I miss Wonderland'
```

But my output is the original string with the prefix removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that you do not in fact want to remove the whole "string" or "line", but rather the word? Then you'll want to split your string into words:

```
words = test.split(' ')
```

And now iterate through each element in `words`, performing your check on the first letter. Lastly, combine these elements back into one string:

```
result = ""
for word in words:
    if !word.startswith(prefix):
        result += (word + " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

`for line in text` in your case will iterate over each character in the text, not each word. So when it gets to e.g., `'#'` in `'#feeling'`, it will remove the `#`, but `'feeling'` will remain because none of the other characters in that string start with/are `'#'` or `'#'`. You can confirm that your code is going character by character by doing:

```
for line in text:
    print(line)
```

Try the following instead, which does the filtering in a single line:

```
text = 'I miss Wonderland #feeling sad @omg'
prefix = ('#','@')
words = text.split()    # Split the text into a list of its individual words.

# Join only those words that don't start with prefix
print(' '.join([word for word in words if not word.startswith(prefix)]))
```